# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'." error on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm getting an error at this statement:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.User")
```

Error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The code is below. I'm assuming the connection is fine because nothing happens unless I execute the query? Am I doing something wrong?

```
SERVER = 'LAPTOP-1E7UL24T\SQLEXPRESS02'
DATABASE = 'PT'
DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
DATABASE_CONNECTION=f'Driver={DRIVER};SERVER={SERVER};Database={DATABASE};Trusted_Connection=yes;'
print(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(DATABASE_CONNECTION)

cursor=cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.User")
```

Comment: Dale,  Im just getting "syntax error near User"

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM User")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and needs to be escaped, commonly by using square brackets e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[User]
```

But double quotes also work:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo."User"
```

Although it will make your life (and any developers who follow) a lot easier if you just avoid using reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running into the deprecated data types: `IMAGE`, `TEXT` and `NVARCHAR`. They need to be handled differently.

See their github [issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1058), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175267/how-to-retrieve-ms-sql-data-from-deprecated-text-field-using-python-pyodbc-pyo) SO answer.