# How to retrieve MS SQL data from deprecated TEXT field using python pyodbc? (pyodbc.ProgrammingError 42000)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

According to the developers of the [`pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/) (python ODBC connector), the data field in MS SQL databases with **`TEXT`** type have been deprecated. Therefore development support for reading these fields results in the error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. (306) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Clearly, I do not have the possibility to change this legacy DB in any way, and can only read it. I am reading separate columns using the following DB structure and code, which works fine until it hits a field of the `TEXT` type.

The table schema type for that is `(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)`:

```sql
mytable  col_name  text  2147483647
```

I'm then trying to reading all the columns (one at a time) using:

```py
def get_data(table_list):
    cursor = connect()
    for table, column in table_list:
        SQLA = 'SELECT TOP 1 [{}] as data FROM [{}] ORDER BY [{}] DESC;'.format(column, table, column)
        cursor.execute(SQLA)
        
        while 1:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if not row:
                break
            print(' Data : {}'.format(row.data))
    db_close(cursor)
```

This works fine until it hits the first column with a TEXT type (as shown above).

Running the same query from powershell (pwsh) yields the same result:

```
$ iex "$qcmd 'SELECT TOP 1 [notes] FROM [mytable ] ORDER BY [notes] DESC;' -W"

Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Server DBSQL01, Line 1
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

I'm using the following versions:

```
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)
 Dec 28 2017 15:03:48
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

- `pyodbc  4.0.32`
- Python: `3.10.3`

---

**How can I read the data in all the TEXT fields using a query as above?**

Comment: "Clearly, I do not have the possibility to change this legacy DB in any way..." - Can you not even update it to change TEXT columns to NVARCHAR(MAX)?  I'm not overly experienced with pyodbc bit I would think that should be all that's needed.  Otherwise, if your SQL is client-side you could try CAST or CONVERT of TEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX) in the SQL.

Comment: I wouldn't blame pyodbc for this, `text` has been deprecated since (at least) SQL Server 2005. _The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._ REF: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around the issue after having been pointed to use the *cast()* function. By adding a blacklist of the columns using the `TEXT` datatype, I can now get the actual data with:

```py
blacklist2 += ['code']
if (column in blacklist):
   SQLA = 'SELECT TOP 1 [{}] AS data FROM [{}] ORDER BY cast([{}] as varchar(MAX)) DESC;'.format(column, table, column,column)
```

There are also other *deprecated* datatypes, of `IMAGE` and `NVARCHAR`, that also need to be handled differently.